# iOS Developers - Are you using autolayout?

Tags: ios

I tried to really learn it but it's the most frustrating interface I've ever used in my life. I understand the concepts but positioning things just where I want them is very difficult. So, are you guys using it?

Comment: This is a survey, not a question. [Real questions have answers.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/) Don't ask questions that can't be definitively answered.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know where better to ask.

Comment: Yes. But you have to RTFM rather than just trying it and hoping it will work. There are lots of questions on SO where the poster has clearly not read the documentation. In addition, there are many WWDC videos from 2012 onwards that cover how to use Autolayout and common errors and how to fix them. But people just seem too lazy to spend a few hours watching them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's extremely hard to grasp at first but it's a wonderful tool.